# How could I change the data order in localStorage in Backbone.js app?

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I'm making a Backbone app now and using a backbone.localstorage plugin to persist the data. My app has some sortable items so I hope every time I sort the items, the data order in localStorage will also change. And next time I refresh the whole page, the page will be rendered by the sorted data. But it seems that backbone.localstorage will persist the data in its creation order. Could someone give me some ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your models to appear in an explicit order then include a [`comparator`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) in your collection and, possibly, a position number in each model.

[Local storage is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage):

> a means through which string key/value pairs can be securely stored and later retrieved for use.

Note the *key/value pairs*, that means that you're dealing with, more or less, a big hash table and those are usually unordered. Furthermore, from the [fine specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-storage-interface):

> The order of keys is user-agent defined, but must be consistent within an object so long as the number of keys doesn't change. (Thus, adding or removing a key may change the order of the keys, but merely changing the value of an existing key must not.)

So there is no particular order inside local storage. If you want a specific order, you have to arrange for it yourself.

In your case, you'd probably have a `position` or `index` property in your models that would behave like an array index; then, in your collection:

```
comparator: function(m) { return m.get('position') } // or 'index'
```

You could also use a two argument `comparator` function:

```
comparator: function(a, b) {
    a = a.get('position');
    b = b.get('position');
    if(a < b)
        return -1;
    else if(a > b)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

You'd have to maintain the position indexes as you move models around but that shouldn't be terribly difficult. You could also order the data by `position` after pulling it out of local storage but before putting it in your collection and then assign `position` values while writing the models into local storage.

Comment: So if I assign an index for each model and include a comparator in collection, then every time I use `this.collection.fetch()` to load the data and render the view, it will be shown in an ordered way automatically, right?

Comment: @chaonextdoor: If you include the comparator then the collection will be ordered using that comparator every time you call [`add`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-add) on the collection (unless you specify the `at` option to `add`). This can make it a little tricky to re-order things manually so you might want to only worry about the positions coming out of and going into local storage.

Comment: So if I call `this.collection.add()`, the model will be inserted in the right place. But if I call `this.collection.fetch()` at the very begining to render the initial page, the whole page is still unordered and I have to sort them manually first and then render the initial view, right?

Comment: `add` will put it in the right place if you have a `comparator` and the model has the right `position` property, same goes for `fetch`.

Comment: One more question, I tried to use `localStorage.data` and it would show all the data. But how could I access the specific data item in the localStorage? It seems that localStorage data always has a random key such as `714b097d-875e-7f18-b004-665676d98974`. How could I access the value associated with this key without refering to these annoying random keys?

Comment: Those are the default IDs from the local storage adapter (https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/backbone.localStorage.js#L39), assign your IDs and the adapter will use them.